# Automatically Generated Menu pages

Tags: menus

I am a designer for a website, which I had a developer build in wordperss for me.

Each time a new page is created, it is automatically added to my menu bar. Is this something the developer has built into the code, or is it something I can turn off?

Comment: You'll need to do some research on your own, and give more information. For instance, have you checked with your developer? What's "my menu bar"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major things you need check for to resolve this.  If your site is using the WordPress menus, then under Appearance | Menus is a checkbox that if ticked will automatically add all new top-level pages to the menu.  Unticking that box will stop the behavior.

If you check that area and no menus are defined, then the theme is using wp_list_pages() to generate a menu.  If the menu bar appears at the top of the content, then check the theme's header.php file for the function.  If your menu is on a sidebar, check for the function in sidebar.php.

If neither of the above applies, you might check your Widgets to see if something there is doing it.